# MySQL View with Union Error - "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"

Tags: mysql, view

I'm getting this error and I don't know how to resolve.  It works fine as a normal query, but I'd like for it to be a view:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `myTable`.`vw_videos` AS

SELECT DISTINCT theVideos.videoID FROM
    (SELECT video_youtube_id AS videoID FROM videos
    UNION
    SELECT entry_video AS videoID FROM vw_entry_info) AS theVideos
WHERE videoID != "";
```

I keep getting "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause".  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've just stumbled on: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16757
It's a very annoying "feature" of MySQL which you can work-around by creating separate subviews and referencing them in your latter query.